# page becomes unresponsive when ng-table is used for large data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

for my single page application, I am  using [ng-table](http://ng-table.com/#/). I am using it to display an array of data. The array on average has around 26000 entries. The data is getting fetched in a few seconds through http get method. But when I use ng-table to display this data (with grouping), entire page becomes un-responsive for some time. What do I do?

I do not want use pagination, the requirement is that I show the entire data in the table.

Comment: You could try and implement lazy loading so that initially the table only contains some of the data, but upon scrolling it adds to the data, so that angular doesn't have to handle all the 26000 records at once but like 100 at a time

Comment: can you give more details on how to do that

Comment: I haven't tried making one by myself, but with quick googling I found [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/3d274f0f-f47a-4bf0-91ec-8ebad479881b/entry/how_to_implement_a_table_with_lazy_loading_infinite_scroll_in_angularjs?lang=en) which seems like a good place to start. :)

Comment: thanks a lot, will try lazy loading

Comment: You can see my answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477188/how-to-use-page-scroll-on-nggrideventscroll/31576404#31576404 This is the way I solved the problem you currently have. Also,  you can look at ui-grid. They use data virtualization (rendering only what's on the screen) to avoid performance issues and handle large data http://ui-grid.info/